# how to post an array from view to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

i want to access value of country_id and country_name  from this decoding string by json_decode() but it's not working my decoded data is priting by print_r() is given below:

```
{"country_Data":
                 [
                   {"country_id":"1","country_name":"India"},          

                   {"country_id":"2","country_name":"Saudi Arabia"},

                   {"country_id":"3","country_name":"UAE"}
                 ]
 }
```

i tried like
    `foreach($data['country_Data'][0]['country_id'])`
but no luck.please help thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use the for loop like this

```
$data = json_decode($json_data, true); // 2nd param converts output to associative arrays

foreach($data['country_Data'] as $country_data) {
  print_r($country_data);
  echo $country_data['country_id'] .', '. $country_data['country_name'];
}
```

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() . It is giving error

Comment: The code that I have shown assumes that your have proper $data array. Use json_decode on the to get $data then try printing it using print_r.

Answer (score 1):

Did you decode the $data json first?

```
$data = json_decode($json)

foreach($data['country_Data'] as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() . It is giving error

Answer (score 1):

```
//Your json encoded string
$string = '{"country_Data": [{"country_id": "1","country_name": "India"},{"country_id": "2","country_name": "Saudi Arabia"},{"country_id": "3","country_name": "UAE"}]}';

//your data decoded in an array
$arr = json_decode($string,true);

foreach($arr as $item)
{
        foreach($item as $value){
                print_r($value['country_id']." ".$value['country_name']."\n");
            }

}

//Printed data
1 India
2 Saudi Arabia
3 UAE
```

http://ideone.com/SmklSx

Answer (score 0):

since json_decode creates an object from your data (by default) you need to acces it as a property:

like this:

```
foreach($countryArray->country_Data as $row) {
    echo $row->country_id;
}
```

or use the loop the other guys suggested but you need to make sure json_decode gives back an array, you can do this setting the second parameter to true,

```
$countryArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data = json_decode($json_data, true); 

foreach($data as $cd) {
print_r($cd);
 echo $cd['country_id'] .', '. $cd['country_name'];
 }
```

Comment: I think it would bem ore helpful for the op and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Answer (score 0):

```
`$data = '{"country_Data":[{"country_id":"1","country_name":"India"},   
          {"country_id":"2","country_name":"Saudi Arabia"}, 
          {"country_id":"3","country_name":"UAE"}]}';

 $json = json_decode($data,true);
 foreach($json as $res)
 {
    foreach($res as $key => $value)
     {
        $datavalue[]=$value;
     }
 }
 //print_r($datavalue);
 foreach($datavalue as $v)
 {
    echo $v['country_name'].'<br />';
 }
```

`